# Mongoose find or multiple columns not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

If keyword maches in `category.title` then it is giving result otherwise it is not matching with any other fields.  Can somebody tell me what is the issue here?
Also tried `NewsModel.find().or(filters)` without `$or` key, still not working.

```
  let filters = {};

  if (keyword) {
    filters = {
      $or: [
        {
          title: keyword,
        },
        {
          shortDescription: keyword,
        },
        {
          detailDescription: keyword,
        },
        {
          "category.title": keyword,
        },
      ],
    };
  }

  const response = await NewsModel.find(filters);
```

mongoose:6.3.0

**Update: DB collection added**

```
 {
        "_id": "625b83518b1eaedc58a74196",
        "title": "Moon Knight",
        "shortDescriptipn": "Embrace the chaos.",
        "detailDescription": "When Steven Grant, a mild-mannered gift-shop employee...",
        "category": [
            {
                "_id": "625b7dfd00e7f082f6d8d9fb",
                "title": "Entertainment"
            }
        ],
        "createdAt": "2022-04-17T03:02:41.353Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-04-17T03:02:41.353Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
```

If I am searching for `Entertainment`, I get result but if I am searching for `Moon Knight`, I get empty array.

Comment: can you add a sample database collection for the same, will be easier to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to make it work, also you have misspelled `shortDescriptipn` in the database.

What i did is, i used `$or` keyword with regex search so you dont need to write full string, if it contains that part of string, it will return the document and wont be a strict full match case, also i have added option `i` which will make the search case insensitive.

The query will be like:

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {
      title: {
        $regex: keyword,
        $options: "i"
      },
      
    },
    {
      shortDescriptipn: {
        $regex: keyword,
        $options: "i"
      },
      
    },
    {
      detailDescription: {
        $regex: keyword,
        $options: "i"
      },
      
    },
    {
      "category.title": {
        $regex: keyword,
        $options: "i"
      }, 
    },
  ],
})
```

You can also check the query here : https://mongoplayground.net/p/7zuhbaNTWJY

Let me know, if you have any doubts in comments.

Comment: It worked. Extra +1 for the regex search. Thanks for noticing out the details and help. @Ashishssoni

Comment: Now it is working with this also ```NewsModel.find().or(filters)```

Comment: much appreciated @Belal, cheers mate